# Matplotlib: applying cellColours to only certain columns/cells

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Got myself in a pickle.

I'm creating a basic table in Matplotlib (via Pandas, but that's not the issue).  What I'm trying to accomplish is to create a table where the first column, which will be string values, remains white...but columns 2,3,4,5,6 are floating/integers and will be colored by a custom normalized colormap.

I've started with the basics, and created the 'colored' table via the code below.  This only plots the columns with integer values at this point, see here:
[image: Test_Table]

What I ulimately need to do is plot this with an additional column, say before column 'A' or after column 'F' which holds string values, e.g. ['MBIAS', 'RMSE', 'BAGSS', 'MBIAS', 'MBIAS'].

However if I try to apply the cellColours method in the code below to a table that mixes lists of strings and float/integers, it obviously fails.

Is there a method to apply a cellColours scheme to only certain cells, or row/columns? Can I loop through, applying the custom colormap to specific cells?

Any help or tips would be appreciated!

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import *


#Create sample data in pandas dataframe
idx = Index(np.arange(1,6))
df = DataFrame(abs(2*np.random.randn(5, 5)), index=idx, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
model = ['conusarw', 'conusarw', 'conusarw', 'nam04', 'emhrrr']
df['Model'] = model
df1 = df[['A','B','C','D','E']]
test = df1.round({'A':2,'B':2,'C':2,'D':2,'E':2})
print(test)
vals = test.values
print(vals)

#Creates normalized list (from 0-1) based a user provided range and center of distribution.
norm = matplotlib.colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=0,vcenter=1,vmax=10)
#Merges colormap to the normalized data based on customized normalization pattern from above.
colours = plt.cm.coolwarm(norm(vals))

#Create figure in Matplotlib in which to plot table.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=False, xticks=[], yticks=[])
#Plot table, using pandas dataframe information and data.
#Customized lists of data and names can also be provided.
the_table=plt.table(cellText=vals, rowLabels=model, colLabels=df.columns,
                    loc='center', cellColours=colours)

plt.savefig('test_table.png')
```

Comment: Dataframe styling is worth looking into for future reference https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the fast vectorized call `colours = plt.cm.coolwarm(norm(vals))`, you can just use regular Python loops with if-tests. The code below loops through the individual rows, then through the individual elements and test whether they are numeric. A similar loop prepares the rounded values. Speed is not really a problem, unless you'd have thousands of elements.

(The code uses `import pandas as pd`, as `import * from pandas` isn't recommended.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgba, TwoSlopeNorm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create sample data in pandas dataframe
idx = pd.Index(np.arange(1, 6))
df = pd.DataFrame(abs(2 * np.random.randn(5, 5)), index=idx, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
df['Model'] = ['conusarw', 'conusarw', 'conusarw', 'nam04', 'emhrrr']

cmap = plt.cm.coolwarm
norm = TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=0, vcenter=1, vmax=10)
colours = [['white' if not np.issubdtype(type(val), np.number) else cmap(norm(val)) for val in row]
           for row in df.values]
vals = [[val if not np.issubdtype(type(val), np.number) else np.round(val, 2) for val in row]
        for row in df.values]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=False, xticks=[], yticks=[])
the_table = plt.table(cellText=vals, rowLabels=df['Model'].to_list(), colLabels=df.columns,
                      loc='center', cellColours=colours)
plt.show()
```

[image: table with different color for numbers]

PS: If speed is a concern, the following code is a bit trickier. It uses:

- setting the "bad color" of a colormap
- `pd.to_numeric(..., errors='coerce')` to convert all strings to nans
- as `pd.to_numeric()` only works for 1D arrays, `ravel()` and `reshape()` are used
- using the same arrays, `np.where` can do the rounding

```py
cmap = plt.cm.coolwarm.copy()
cmap.set_bad('white')
norm = TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=0, vcenter=1, vmax=10)
values = pd.to_numeric(df.values.ravel(), errors='coerce').reshape(df.shape)
colours = cmap(norm(values))
vals = np.where(np.isnan(values), df.values, np.round(values, 2))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=False, xticks=[], yticks=[])
the_table = plt.table(cellText=vals, rowLabels=df['Model'].to_list(), colLabels=df.columns,
                      loc='center', cellColours=colours)
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you for this!  I was in the processes of pulling the normalized color list & data list, and adding additional list elements (string values as the first element of the data list, all white color values as the first element of the color list) and then plotting the physical lists in the table.  That method appears to work, but is a mess of steps and ugly code.  This is much more compact and portable.  Thank you!